# WPF Datepicker scroll through dates in textbox

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I would like to scroll using the arrow keys through the day month and year fields in the datepicker textbox.

I am guessing this will be a two step solution:
1- break up month day year into individual fields that the user 'clicks' into.
2- once the user has focus of the either day year or month then they can use arrow keys to scroll up /down.

anyone done this before with wpf?

Answer (score 1):

Found this project has a date time with up / down:
http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/